# Multiple conditions and comparing two different data types using Ansible

Tags: loops, ansible

I have ansible variable which is a dictionary time and I want to compare that with a string variable or comma separated input. Following is the playbook that I am trying to compile using

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    cluster:
      name:
        - "raj"
        - "kiran"
        - "Pavan"
    inputcluster: 
      - "raj"
  tasks:
    # inner.yml
    - debug:
        msg: "outer item={{ outer_item.cluster.name }} "
      with_items:
        - cluster:
            name:
              - "raj"
              - "kiran"
              - "Pavan"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: outer_item
      when: 
        - inputcluster 
        - outer_item.cluster.name == inputcluster`
```

I want echo statement to print only "raj" by comparing the string with the dictionary. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to loop over name list to match it and to iterate over two lists you need nested loop. This can do the trick.

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    cluster:
      name:
        - "raj"
        - "kiran"
        - "Pavan"
    inputcluster: 
      - "raj"
  tasks:
    # inner.yml
    - debug:
        msg: "outer item={{ item[1] }} "
      with_nested:
        - "{{ inputcluster }}"
        - "{{ cluster.name }}"            
      when: (item[0] == item[1])
```

Comment: Thank you very much, It works. I was wondering how to compare two different data types. It is working now and i am able to use it in my ansible role. Thank you Kanwar Saad